# “Je vraiment les aime” or “Je les aime vraiment”?

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, adverbes

I want to say "I really like them." But, which comes first? “Vraiment les aime” or “les aime vraiment”?

Comment: At any rate, you can't insert anything but *ne* and personal pronouns between *je* and the verb. So it is not possible to have something like *je \*vraiment les aime*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je les aime vraiment.

OR

Vraiment, je les aime.

Vraiment is an adverb that modifies the verb, aimer. French places adverbs after the conjugated verb. Longer adverbs can be placed in at the beginning of the phrase for emphasis.

About the placement of adverbs, [laits.utexas.edu/tex/pr/adv2.html#Place](http://laits.utexas.edu/tex/pr/adv2.html#Place) says:

> **adverbs that modify an adjective or another adverb**
>
> Adverbs are placed directly before the adjective or adverb that they
>   modify.
>
> **adverbs that modify a verb**
>
> Adverbs are usually placed immediately after the conjugated verb. If
>   the verb is negative, the adverb is placed after the negation.

Comment: I don't get the point about "long" and "short" adverbs. "Je les aime considérablement" is correct and at the end of the sentence (I guess it is a long adverb)

Comment: Goog link, you may add it to your answer and correct your assertion :)

Answer (score 1):

The adverb refers mostly to :

- **Verbe :** *Je les **aime** vraiment.* (After)
- **Adjective :** *Le gâteau est vraiment **délicieux**.* (Before)
- **Adverbe :** *Vous serez vraiment **mieux** ainsi.* (Before)
- **a sentence or a proposition :** *Vraiment, **vous n'avez pas de chance avec cette voiture.*** (Before)

**Source :** http://grammaire.reverso.net/1_1_28_Ladverbe.shtml

Comment: Non, c'est *vraiment* qui qualifie *mieux*, pas le contraire. L'adverbe vient toujours avant, sauf pour un verbe conjugé à un temps simple.

Comment: C'est ce que j'ai fais, mais je ne peux pas le mettre plus en évidence.